# Design class attributes to match inconsistent keys in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, attributes

I had some difficulties to write my question, so I have maybe badly written my search queries, but I have not found anything that can help me.

I am trying to parse a file in the following way: I build dictionaries using regular expressions. Then I try to create objects where the value for each key populates the value of each attribute in my class. See the code below.

```
for k, v in element.items():
  attr = k
  setattr(thisinstance, attr, v)
else:
  continue
```

(Where thisinstance refers to the selection of the correct instance above in the code.)

This works very well if the key and the attributes are eg "owner". But it can't if the key is eg "the owner is". I could create the attribute "the_owner_is" but how to make the key matches this attribute?

Unsatisfactory solution I've found so far is to change the key value before evaluating equality with attributes. Is there a way to avoid to hard code each variant?

In advance thank you!

Comment: Can you please explain why do you that in first place?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes  (and all names in general) can't have whitespace in their names.

Use `str.replace` to change the key name

```
attr = k.replace(' ', '_')
```

Comment: Actually `setattr` and `getattr` allow whitespace in attribute names, it is only the `.name` notation that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could assing the whole dictionary into a class attribute, and use dictionary notation to access the values.